# why doesn't this line of code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to basically make it so the user can't click #shareheart twice in a row, making the animation screw up. Maybe you could say i'm trying to create an active state without adding and removing classes?

why doesn't this work? The first piece of code is what's not working, it's not following this if statement, did i do something wrong here?

```
if($('.share-text').not(':animated') && $('.share-text span').is(':visible')) {
    // do something
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
$('#shareheart').click(function() {
    if ($('.share-text:animated').length == 0 && $('.share-text span').is(':visible')) {
        $('.share-text span').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 800, function() {
            $("#share-what").fadeOut(400)
            $('.share-text').stop(true, false).animate({'width': 'toggle','padding-left': 'toggle','padding-right': 'toggle'}, 800)
            $('#short-url').css('background-image', "url('images/drink.png')");
        })
    } else {
        $('.share-text').stop(false, true).animate({'width': 'toggle','padding-left': 'toggle','padding-right': 'toggle'}, 800, function() {
            $('.share-text span').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 800)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. Don't put code in the title, it's not very readable. 2. **Do** put code in proper formatting, see the notes conveniently placed to the right of the editing area. 3. Define "not working."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can combine your condition to a single selector:

```
if($(".share-text:not(:animated) span:visible").length)
{
}
```

The condition will return `0` (a false value) if it `share-text` is a animated, or if the span is invisible.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.share-text').not(':animated')
```

...will give you a jQuery object (and so will always be truthy if tested as a boolean). [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) doesn't test a condition and return the result of the text, it *filters* the elements matched by the jQuery object.

You haven't said what the code is supposed to do, but you might want:

```
if ($('.share-text:animated').length == 0 && $('.share-text span').is(':visible')) {
    // do something
}
```

...if the first half is looking to see if there are no elements with the "share-text' class that are not animated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you misunderstand the functioning of [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). It *filters* the set, it *does not* test whether the elements are conform to the given selector. You probably want something like:

```
!$('.share-text').is(':animated')
```